# Flex: Displaying more than 5 things at a time in a DropDown (ComboBox)

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, drop-down-menu

I have a ComboBox in Flex with about 20 items. How do I display all of them in a dropdown with no scroll bar? Right now, Flex displays 5 at a time in the dropdown and puts a scrollbar to scroll for more.

Here's an example:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/07/18/setting-the-dropdown-menu-border-thickness-and-border-color-on-a-combobox-control-in-flex/#more-711

How do I make the dropdown bigger in this example so it shows all 10 items at once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it: 'rowCount' is the property to change. It defaults to 5.

Comment: i can't find the equivalent of this property in flex 4.5

Answer (score 0):

For ones who search for same thing for spark combo: 
for spark components that extend `SkinnableDataContainer` (including `ComboBox`) you can specify layout with

`requestedMinRowCount` , `requestedMaxRowCount`

properties, and do as much changes as you want with the help of skin(this layout directly goes to `DataGroup` skinpart inside skin).